# Google Cloud Datastore maximum number of kinds

Tags: google-cloud-datastore

Is there a limit in the number of kinds I can create? My assumption is no and I didnt see anything in the Limits page in the documentation but I need to know for sure.

Answer (score 2):

There are no limits to the number of kinds specifically.

However, please check the [limits regarding indexes](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/limits).

Keep in mind that as stated in the documentation, the values are subject to change.

Also, check the [Cloud Datastore Best Practices](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/best-practices).

Comment: I tried searching any documentation or even anyone who ever had such an issue but there is nothing. However, if by any means you hit a quota, you can request a quota increase. But please make sure you are not hitting any limits on indexes (the link I've included in my answer)